# Too many errors [invalid] ecountered when loading data into bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I enriched a public dataset of reddit comments with data from LIWC (Linguistic Inquiry and Word Count). I have 60 files á 600mb. The idea is now to upload to BigQuery, getting them together and analyze the results. Alas i faced some problems.

For a first test I had a test sample with 200 rows and 114 columns. [Here is a link to the csv i used](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5eqrit7mx9sp3vh/dat2.csv?dl=0)

I first asked on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/4snjk6/problems_with_loading_data_into_bigquery/) and fhoffa provided a really good answer. The problem seems to be the newlines (/n) in the body_raw column, as redditors often include them in their text. It seems BigQuery cannot process them.

I tried to transfer the original data, which i transfered to storage, back to BigQuery, unedited, untouched, but the same problem. BigQuery cannot even process the original data, which comes from BigQuery...?

Anyway, I can open the csv without problems in other programs such as R, which means that the csv itself is not damaged or the schema is inconsistent. So fhoffa's command should get rid of it.

```
bq load --allow_quoted_newlines --allow_jagged_rows --skip_leading_rows=1 tt.delete_201607a myproject.newtablename gs://my_testbucket/dat2.csv body_raw,score_hidden,archived,name,author,author_flair_text,downs,created_utc,subreddit_id,link_id,parent_id,score,retrieved_on,controversiality,gilded,id,subreddit,ups,distinguished,author_flair_css_class,WC,Analytic,Clout,Authentic,Tone,WPS,Sixltr,Dic,function,pronoun,ppron,i,we,you,shehe,they,ipron,article,prep,auxverb,adverb,conj,negate,verb,adj,compare,interrog,number,quant,affect,posemo,negemo,anx,anger,sad,social,family,friend,female,male,cogproc,insight,cause,discrep,tentat,certain,differ,percept,see,hear,feel,bio,body,health,sexual,ingest,drives,affiliation,achieve,power,reward,risk,focuspast,focuspresent,focusfuture,relativ,motion,space,time,work,leisure,home,money,relig,death,informal,swear,netspeak,assent,nonflu,filler,AllPunc,Period,Comma,Colon,SemiC,QMark,Exclam,Dash,Quote,Apostro,Parenth,OtherP
```

The output was:

```
Too many positional args, still have ['body_raw,score_h...]
```

If i take away "tt.delete_201607a" from the command, i get the same error message I have often seen now:

```
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'xx': Too many errors encountered.
```

So i do not know what to do here. Should I get rid of /n with Python? That would take probably days (although im not sure, i am not a programmer), as my complete data set is around 55 million rows. 
Or do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I checked again, and I was able to load the file you left on dropbox without a problem.

First I made sure to download your original file:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/5eqrit7mx9sp3vh/dat2.csv?dl=0
```

Then I run the following command:

```
bq load --allow_quoted_newlines --allow_jagged_rows --skip_leading_rows=1 \
   tt.delete_201607b dat2.csv\?dl\=0 \
   body_raw,score_hidden,archived,name,author,author_flair_text,downs,created_utc,subreddit_id,link_id,parent_id,score,retrieved_on,controversiality,gilded,id,subreddit,ups,distinguished,author_flair_css_class,WC,Analytic,Clout,Authentic,Tone,WPS,Sixltr,Dic,function,pronoun,ppron,i,we,you,shehe,they,ipron,article,prep,auxverb,adverb,conj,negate,verb,adj,compare,interrog,number,quant,affect,posemo,negemo,anx,anger,sad,social,family,friend,female,male,cogproc,insight,cause,discrep,tentat,certain,differ,percept,see,hear,feel,bio,body,health,sexual,ingest,drives,affiliation,achieve,power,reward,risk,focuspast,focuspresent,focusfuture,relativ,motion,space,time,work,leisure,home,money,relig,death,informal,swear,netspeak,assent,nonflu,filler,AllPunc,Period,Comma,Colon,SemiC,QMark,Exclam,Dash,Quote,Apostro,Parenth,OtherP,oops
```

As mentioned in reddit, you need the following options:

- `--allow_quoted_newlines`: There are newlines inside some strings, hence the CSV is not strictly newline delimited.
- `--allow_jagged_rows`: Not every row has the same number of columns.
- `,oops`: There is an extra column in some rows. I added this column to the list of columns.

When it says "too many positional arguments", it's because your command says:

```
tt.delete_201607a myproject.newtablename
```

Well, `tt.delete_201607a` is how I named my table. `myproject.newtablename` is how you named your table. Choose one, not both.

Are you sure you are not able to load the sample file you left on dropbox? Or you are getting errors from rows I can't find on that file?

Comment: Ah ok!! Well with your help it worked now, thank you!